# Input dimension for tf.nn.in_top_k

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the TF documentation with respect to in_top_k: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k where it states that `targets` should be a vector of `batch size`

Nevertheless, I'm continuously prompted with the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): targets must be
>   1-dimensional
>            [[Node: in_top_k/InTopKV2 = InTopKV2[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Cas t_2/_4305, sub/_4307, in_top_k/InTopKV2/k)]]

In my case, my `predictions` and `targets` inputs have the following shapes:

- predictions: `Tensor("Cast_2:0", shape=(128, 1000), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:0)`
- targets: `Tensor("sub:0", shape=(128,), dtype=int32, device=/device:GPU:0)`

From my understanding, there is still something not ok with my `targets` label, and despite using different combinations of tf.reshape or tf.squeeze I cannot seem to find where is the error. Is there any way to work around this issue?

Comment: Can you show us a relevant fragment of your code? Is it possible that you are passing the function parameters in the wrong order?

Comment: The solution in this case was that even though the tensor was of the correct type (int32), values were encoded as float. This created problems with in_top_k